# Use find, wc, and sed to count lines

Tags: bash, sed, find, wc

I was trying to use sed to count all the lines based on a particular extension.

```
find -name '*.m' -exec wc -l {} \; | sed ...
```

I was trying to do the following, how would I include sed in this particular line to get the totals.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You may also get the nice formatting from wc with :

```
wc `find -name '*.m'`
```

Comment: Add `-type f` to avoid the case of a directory name that matches: `wc $(find -type f -name '*.m')`

Comment: wc $(find -name '*.m') is prettier.

Comment: This will break for any file names which contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: @tripleee How would you recover from white-spaces in this instance? I am currently have this issue.

Comment: @Workingdollar https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 and/or several of the other answers on this page.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for the documentation. I found that this worked most effectively for me ```find . -name '*.m' -exec wc {} \;```

Answer (score 19):

Most of the answers here won't work well for a large number of files. Some will break if the list of file names is too long for a single command line call, others are inefficient because `-exec` starts a new process for every file. I believe a robust and efficient solution would be:

```
find . -type f -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
```

Using `cat` in this way is fine, as its output is piped straight into `wc` so only a small amount of the files' content is kept in memory at once. If there are too many files for a single invocation of `cat`, `cat` will be called multiple times, but all the output will still be piped into a single `wc` process.

Comment: Or use the standard/portable form instead: `find . -type f -name '*.m' -exec cat {} + | wc -l`.

Comment: how to modify this to print out total lines for each file among with the file name?

Comment: @loretoparisi Then trivially run `-exec wc -l {} +` instead of `-print0 | xargs ...`. Using `+` with `-exec` might end up running more than one instance of `wc -l` and then you will need to sum the totals from each run for the overall total. Or if you don't care about totals, just remove those lines with `grep -v`; or, use `-exec wc -l {} \;` to run a separate instance of `wc` on each file, at a somewhat higher processing cost.

Answer (score 6):

You can `cat` all files through a single `wc` instance to get the total number of lines:

```
find . -name '*.m' -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 5):

On modern GNU platforms wc and find take -print0 and -files0-from parameters that can be combined into a command that count lines in files with total at the end. Example:

```
find . -name '*.c' -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=-
```

Answer (score 4):

you could use sed also for counting lines in place of wc:

```
 find . -name '*.m' -exec sed -n '$=' {} \;
```

where `'$='` is a "special variable" that keep the count of lines

EDIT

you could also try something like [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/)

Comment: find . -name '*.m' -exec sed -n 'where $=' {} \;

Is this it?

Comment: That is not the total though, added together.

Comment: OK, I ended up with this.

$ find . -name '*.m' -exec sed -n '$=' {} \; | sum -
22696     1

Comment: __where '$=' is a "special variable" that keep the count of lines__. You jest sire! `$=` represents an address and a command. The `$` is last line, the command `=` is current line number, in conjunction with `-n` switch which supresses pattern space printout. The outcome is it __counts__ the number of lines fed to it.

Comment: @dfa Thanks. How to print the filename before the count?

Answer (score 3):

Hm, solution with **cat** may be problematic if you have many files, especially big ones.

Second solution doesn't give total, just lines per file, as I tested.

I'll prefer something like this:

```
find . -name '*.m' | xargs wc -l | tail -1
```

This will do the job fast, no matter how many and how big files you have.

Comment: If there are too many files for a single command line, xargs will chunk them and this will only give the total for the final chunk.

Answer (score 1):

sed is not the proper tool for counting. Use awk instead:

```
find . -name '*.m' -exec awk '{print NR}' {} +
```

Using + instead of \; forces find to call awk every N files found (like with xargs).

Comment: Funny, I actually meant to say awk

Answer (score 1):

For big directories we should use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.m' -exec sed -n '$=' '{}' + 2>/dev/null | awk '{ total+=$1 }END{print total}' 

# alternative using awk twice
find . -type f -name '*.m' -exec awk 'END {print NR}' '{}' + 2>/dev/null | awk '{ total+=$1 }END{print total}'
```