# How to print out the number of lines in an output command

Tags: bash

For example:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

What is the easiest way to count and display the number of lines the command outputs?

Comment: `wc -l < /etc/password `

Comment: @Raze2dust How about putting your comment in an answer so it can be ticked correct? Possibly without the Google commment. Thanks.

Comment: `wc` accept a filename, so: `wc -l /etc/passwd`

Comment: @Thomas If I had created questions for everything I wanted to know about and gotten immediate answers, I wouldn't have learned 10% of what I know today. I should probably not have put the answer at all, because it defeats the purpose of the google comment.

Comment: @kev: If you use redirection, the output consists only of the count without the filename being repeated back to you. I imagine in this case `cat` is being used as a stand-in for another command (otherwise it's a UUoC.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137094/how-to-count-lines-on-a-document, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114814/count-non-blank-lines-of-code-in-bash, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314679/in-bash-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-variable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412244/use-find-wc-and-sed-to-count-lines, *ad nauseum*. Moderators, please merge answer with some existing question; the first one looks closest to me.

Comment: @Raze2dust See, next time some one googles this problem, they might well find this page on SO and be happy for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

`wc` is the unix utility which counts characters, words, lines etc. Try `man wc` to learn more about it. The `-l` option makes it print only the number of lines (and not characters and other stuff).

So, `wc -l <filename>` will print the number of lines in the file `<filename>`.

You asked about how to count number of lines output from a command line program in general. To do that, you can use pipes in unix. So, you can pipe the output of any command to `wc -l`. In your example, `cat /etc/password` is the command line program you want to count. For that you should do:

```
cat /etc/password | wc -l
```